# Add elements to Convex Hull by using Euclidean distance

Tags: python, dictionary, euclidean-distance

I have a question regarding convex hulls:

I have a dictionary containing the vertices of convex hulls, so it's a key and a 2-dimensional numpy array with varying numbers. The problem is that I would like all of them have the same number.

This I could achieve by "adding" points to the convex hull. This points could be inserted between the points of the convex hull with the largest euclidean distance. I would add those points in a loop until I would reach the desired amount (N=10):

```
'key1': {([2.7, 3.1],
   [2.8, 2.6])}
'key2': {([4.7, 5.2],
   [3.8, 1.6], [4.8, 0.6])}
'key3': {([2.7, 3.1],
   [2.8, 2.6], [1.7, 4.1])}
```

I tried it like this:

```
enter code hfor x in hullpoints:
while len(hullpoints) < 10:
    new_point = (x[0] + x[1])/2
    print(new_point)
hullpoints = hullpoints.np.append(new_point)
```

but this just sends me in an endless loop.

I tried playing around with eucledian distances as well:

```
dist = cdist(hullpoints, hullpoints, metric='euclidean')
bestpair = np.unravel_index(hdist.argmax(), hdist.shape)
new_point = (hullpoints[bestpair[0]] + hullpoints[bestpair[1]])/2
```

but I don't know where to go from here.
I hope someone can help me with this.

BR

Comment: the `new_point` is added outside the while loop...

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, the line that affects `len(hullpoints)` is outside the while loop, so the loop will be endless.

You can fix it by indenting the update line (note: attempted fix for the other lines as well):

```py
while len(hullpoints) < 10:
    x = hullpoints
    new_point = (x[0] + x[1])/2
    print(new_point)
    hullpoints = np.append(hullpoints, new_point)
```

However, there are still problems with this: all additional points will be all the same value: the midpoint between `x[0]` and `x[1]`.

A perhaps simpler approach is:

```py
# reproducible init
ch = {
    'key1': ([2.7, 3.1], [2.8, 2.6]),
    'key2': ([4.7, 5.2], [3.8, 1.6], [4.8, 0.6]),
    'key3': ([2.7, 3.1], [2.8, 2.6], [1.7, 4.1]),
}

n = 10
ch2 = {
    k: tuple([np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], n) for x in v])
    for k, v in ch.items()
}
```

This replaces each segment `x` by an even linear spacing between the extremities. If you are sure `x` has always 2 components (like in your example), you can write `np.linspace(*x, n)` instead of `np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], n)`.

Result, with the values from your example, you get:

```py
>>> ch2
{'key1': (array([2.7       , 2.74444444, 2.78888889, 2.83333333, 2.87777778,
         2.92222222, 2.96666667, 3.01111111, 3.05555556, 3.1       ]),
  array([2.8       , 2.77777778, 2.75555556, 2.73333333, 2.71111111,
         2.68888889, 2.66666667, 2.64444444, 2.62222222, 2.6       ])),
 'key2': (array([4.7       , 4.75555556, 4.81111111, 4.86666667, 4.92222222,
         4.97777778, 5.03333333, 5.08888889, 5.14444444, 5.2       ]),
  array([3.8       , 3.55555556, 3.31111111, 3.06666667, 2.82222222,
         2.57777778, 2.33333333, 2.08888889, 1.84444444, 1.6       ]),
  array([4.8       , 4.33333333, 3.86666667, 3.4       , 2.93333333,
         2.46666667, 2.        , 1.53333333, 1.06666667, 0.6       ])),
 'key3': (array([2.7       , 2.74444444, 2.78888889, 2.83333333, 2.87777778,
         2.92222222, 2.96666667, 3.01111111, 3.05555556, 3.1       ]),
  array([2.8       , 2.77777778, 2.75555556, 2.73333333, 2.71111111,
         2.68888889, 2.66666667, 2.64444444, 2.62222222, 2.6       ]),
  array([1.7       , 1.96666667, 2.23333333, 2.5       , 2.76666667,
         3.03333333, 3.3       , 3.56666667, 3.83333333, 4.1       ]))}
```